# Try catch around list_to_integer doesn't catch error

Tags: erlang

1> foo:inter().
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  foo:inter/0 (foo.erl, line 7)

```
-module(foo).
-compile(export_all).

inter() ->
  A = <<"5a">>,
  B = binary_to_list(A),
  try list_to_integer(B) of
    Result -> Result
  catch
    _ -> {error, bad_integer}
  end.
```

I expected to get {error, bad_integer}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [3 types of exceptions](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/errors.html#id86936) in Erlang: `error`, `exit` and `throw`. `catch` clauses are of the format `Type:Pattern`. When a `Type` is not specified, like in your code, only `throw` exceptions are caught while `list_to_integer` throws an `error`. You can catch all `error` using `error:_` or catch any exception using `_:_`.

```
1> try list_to_integer("5a") of
1>   Result -> Result
1> catch
1>   _:_ -> {error, bad_integer}
1> end.
{error,bad_integer}
```