# Elixir: try do catch exit signals

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

While Elixir encourages us not to use try/catch blocks there are times when they are needed. In an application I wrote I have the following try/catch which works.

```
try do 
  message = GenServer.call(via, :get_messages)
  {:ok, message}
catch 
  :exit, _ -> {:error, "Process uuid no longer exists"}
end
```

In the catch section I changed `:exit, -` to `{:exit, _}` thinking that they were the same thing and that resulted in breaking the code.

My question is what is `:exit, _`

It does not seam to be a tuple, list, etc. Even when I used `_` it did not match. Is catch a macro that expects parameters?

Comment: Relevant: My answer on the 3 types of exceptions in Erlang: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45973542/320615

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elixir is open source and it has a nearly perfect documentation.

[`Kernel.SpecialForms.try/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#try/1)’s subsection on [catching throws and exits](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#try/1-catching-throws-and-exits) reveals the whole thing.

Yes, `try` [is a macro](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.5.2/lib/elixir/lib/kernel/special_forms.ex#L1890) that is inlined by compiler and depending on the clause’s signature is [transpiled to either `:throw, _` or to `_, _`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.5.2/lib/elixir/src/elixir_erl_try.erl#L21).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I suppose part of my question, surprise, was that I was expecting pattern matching in the catch section, and hence a Elixir type like tuple, but because it is a macro it is actually expecting two arguments. I agree the documentation is good, but for a noop finer details can still be non-obvious. Thanks again for your response.